# How do I launch Dota 2 straight into Reborn using a shortcut?

Tags: steam, dota-2

I made a shortcut on the desktop to open Dota: steam://rungameid/570

I found the GameIDs for the betas as follows: 571, 572, 573 and  tried them in the launch shortcut but they do not work.

How do I launch Dota 2 straight into Reborn using a shortcut?

Comment: Note: As of yesterday, Reborn has been defaulted, Source 1 Dota is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple to have Reborn as a non Steam Game in your library. Simply follow those steps :

1) Click on Game > *Add a non Steam Game to my Library*

[image]

2) Click *Browse*

[image]

3) Browse to the Reborn client location. By default it should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\game\bin\win64`

[image]

4) To force 64 bits client instead of 32 : Once the game is in your library, *Right Click* > *Properties*

[image]

5) To force 64 bits client instead of 32 : Modify **Target** with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\game\bin\win64\dota2.exe" -DX11`. Here you can also rename it to **DotA2 Reborn**.

[image]

6) If you want a custom icon to distinguish it faster you can use this :

[image]

I've been launching reborn like this for the past few weeks without trouble. Final result should look like this :

[image]

[Source for the start in 64 bits.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/3ab2su/psa_dota_2_reborn_defaults_to_32bitdx9_heres_how/)

[Credit for the Icon.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/3ab2su/psa_dota_2_reborn_defaults_to_32bitdx9_heres_how/csayrs2)